# How to run ASP.NET Core with Angular template inside Docker container?

Tags: asp.net, angular, docker

## Steps

1. Create a new project using Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core with Angular project template. (Other settings: .NET 6.0, HTTPS enabled, no auth)

[image: Angular project template]

2. Add Container Orchestration Support (Other settings: Docker Compose, Linux)

[image: Add Container Orchestration Support]

3. Run the project using the Docker Compose config via VS

[image: Run project]

### Results

1. The browser opens but just shows an HTTP 404 Not Found error.
2. Container logs do not really help.

```
{"EventId":60,"LogLevel":"Warning","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository","Message":"Storing keys in a directory \u0027/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys\u0027 that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.","State":{"Message":"Storing keys in a directory \u0027/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys\u0027 that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.","path":"/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys","{OriginalFormat}":"Storing keys in a directory \u0027{path}\u0027 that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed."}}
{"EventId":35,"LogLevel":"Warning","Category":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager","Message":"No XML encryptor configured. Key {834abb8d-55b6-4f29-b1a6-4aa8a6468f9e} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.","State":{"Message":"No XML encryptor configured. Key {834abb8d-55b6-4f29-b1a6-4aa8a6468f9e} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.","KeyId":"834abb8d-55b6-4f29-b1a6-4aa8a6468f9e","{OriginalFormat}":"No XML encryptor configured. Key {KeyId:B} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form."}}
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: https://[::]:443","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: https://[::]:443","address":"https://[::]:443","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
{"EventId":14,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","State":{"Message":"Now listening on: http://[::]:80","address":"http://[::]:80","{OriginalFormat}":"Now listening on: {address}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","State":{"Message":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down.","{OriginalFormat}":"Application started. Press Ctrl\u002BC to shut down."}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Hosting environment: Development","State":{"Message":"Hosting environment: Development","envName":"Development","{OriginalFormat}":"Hosting environment: {envName}"}}
{"EventId":0,"LogLevel":"Information","Category":"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime","Message":"Content root path: /app/","State":{"Message":"Content root path: /app/","contentRoot":"/app/","{OriginalFormat}":"Content root path: {contentRoot}"}}
```

I need this project to run on Docker. How can this be done?

I know that the Node is not installed in the Docker container but knowing that doesn't exactly help. How to fix it?

Comment: interesting. i am checking

Comment: Your thing you can check is yourUrl/WeatherForecast to see if asp.net core application is working? i just tried same and got the response from the sample weather controller

Comment: The endpoints from WeatherForecast can be reached, but the front-end part of it does not work and give 404 @KamranShahid

Comment: problem seems that dist is not creating

Comment: @M. Ayoksul is your problem resolved?

Comment: You'll need to add another Dockerfile for the angular app. Out of the box, VS does not add the angular app to the docker file nor it creates a Dockerfile for the Angular app. So Creating a separate file and adding it to the docker-compose might work.

Comment: can you please share the docker file created by visual studio?

Comment: @ShubhamWagh what should that separate file look like? Could you elaborate? A working sample would be appreciated.

Comment: @KamranShahid my problem was not solved. I ended up opting out of Docker entirely.

Comment: @ymz, same issue:
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base`
`WORKDIR /app`
`EXPOSE 80`
`EXPOSE 443`
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build`
`WORKDIR /src`
`COPY ["Ag_Dckr/Ag_Dckr.csproj", "Ag_Dckr/"]`
`RUN dotnet restore "Ag_Dckr/Ag_Dckr.csproj"`
`COPY . .`
`WORKDIR "/src/Ag_Dckr"`
`RUN dotnet build "Ag_Dckr.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build`
`FROM build AS publish`
`RUN dotnet publish "Ag_Dckr.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false`
`FROM base AS final`
`WORKDIR /app`
`COPY --from=publish /app/publish .`
`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Ag_Dckr.dll"]`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the docker info. Because everything is wrapped with dot-net helpers, I really need to set up an environment in order to pin-point the problem. However, using the official angular cli (https://angular.io/cli) seems like a more robust way to kick-start your project while serving your API using dot net. My personal opinion of-course